# RxJs call observable on error and repeat steps

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an observable that submits the form `submit$`. This observable may end up with error with status code `403` what means that a user is not authorised and has to log in first.

Is there a way where I could on specific error code invoke another observable which performs an authorisation process. When authorisation is succeeded I want to repeat the `submit$` without having user to invoke that observable once again.

To illustrate steps I want to have:

1. A user tries to submit and `submit$` is being subscribed
2. This ends up with error with status code `403`
3. Observable calls another `authorise$` observable which has own workflow
4. When `authorise$` succeeds the `submit$` is invoked again
5. The process completes with success or error
6. If There is an error during `authorise$` abort the `submit$` process

Comment: Have you tried using retryWhen()?

Comment: This sounds like work for an interceptor, especially if you have an app where user needs to be logged in to "do stuff", so the interceptor would catch all 403 errors in one place and retries the pending request(s) after successful login.

Answer (score 0):

I tried an approach here where I am separating into two observables, submit$ and authenticationSubmit$, and then I merge them again. I haven't tested it, and I am writing http.post(...) twice, so it is not exactly as you described it.

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

const submit$ = http.post(...);

const authenticationAndSubmit$ = submit$.pipe(
  filter(httpResponse => httpResponse.status === 403),
  switchMap(() => authService.login()),
  filter(authResult => authResult === 'success'),
  switchMap(() => http.post(...))
);

merge(submit$, authenticationAndSubmit$)
  .pipe(
    filter(httpResponse => httpResponse.status === 200),
  )
  .subscribe(httpResponse => {
    // Do something
  });
```